# how to make the individual facets within this combined plot all the exact same size

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg, color=as.factor(carb))) + geom_point()
p1 <- p1 + facet_wrap(~vs, ncol=1)

p2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg ,color=as.factor(carb))) + geom_point()
p2 <- p2 + facet_wrap(~carb)

combined <- p1 + p2 +
  plot_layout(ncol = 2) +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')
```

[image]

The facets in A are wider than the facets in B. I want them to be the exact same size. I am not sure how to proceed with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to set the `widths` or the `design` argument such that the space occupied by plot B is three times wider than for Plot A:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg, color=as.factor(carb))) + geom_point()
p1 <- p1 + facet_wrap(~vs, ncol=1)

p2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg ,color=as.factor(carb))) + geom_point()
p2 <- p2 + facet_wrap(~carb)

p1 + p2 +
  plot_layout(ncol = 2, design = "ABBB") +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')
```

[image]